# DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 307

Tags: python, linux, flutter, ubuntu, fastapi

I am using Flutter Linux app to run some APIs that I wrote with fast APIs running locally on my Ubuntu machine.
APIs are working well when tested with Postman, but I am getting a 307 error when calling them in my Flutter app.
The error shows that I should fix my code, but I have no idea!

```
flutter: Error during registration: DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 307 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.
The status code of 307 has the following meaning: "Redirection: further action needs to be taken in order to complete the request"
Read more about status codes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
In order to resolve this exception you typically have either to verify and fix your request code or you have to fix the server code.
```

here is my flutter auth code

```
class AuthApi{

  StorageManager storageManager =StorageManager();
  AppInterceptor appInterceptor = AppInterceptor();
  String authMsg = '';
  final Dio _dio = Dio();

  Future<bool> login(String email, String password) async {

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(APIs.tokenEndpoint,
        data: { "email": email, "password": password},
       options: Options(headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}),
      );
      print(response.data);
      if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode ==201){
        var  dataObj = LoginResponse.fromJson(response.data);
        print(dataObj.email);
        if (dataObj.token == null ||
            dataObj.token == "") {
          debugPrint("token is null");
          return false;
        }
        storageManager.saveAccessToken(dataObj.token);
        storageManager.saveUserRole(dataObj.role);

        return true;
      }else{
        var data = jsonDecode(response.data);
        authMsg = data["detail"];

        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {

      return false;
    }
  }

 
}
```

change dio into http package resulted in the same error

```
flutter: Registration failed with status: 307
```

postman testing:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-3BxTgAZPGRJwJ5SCIUVJSJCNobPcWfc/view?usp=sharing

I tried:
dio.options.followRedirects = true;

I feel that I should change some settings on my machine!

Comment: Update the question showing a working Postman request. Use HTTP (temporarily) and grab a packet capture of a working vs non-working request.

Comment: @RichardHeap I did edit the question

Comment: Check for trailing slash at the end of URL. 307 is sent automatically by FastAPI when you access endpoint either with a trailing slash when there is not or without when there is one

Comment: Your Postman request shows a third value (`role`) in the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

The error was because that I added a trailing slash at the end of URL, after removing it works as expected.
This answer is mentioned by @sudden_appearance in the comments.